# The computed monthly individual customer payment will be returned for each CreditCustomer object in the object array

Tags: c#, accessor, icomparable

I don't want to post the whole answer to a school assignment, so I'll try to just include enough coding detail to show where I'm hung up.

```
    class Customer : IComparable // class declaration
   {
      public int customerNumber { get; set; }
      public string customerName { get; set; }
      public double amountDue { get; set; }

      // Cust class constructor values assigned through accessors
      public Customer(int number, string name, double due)
      {
         customerNumber = number;
         customerName = name;
         amountDue = due;
      }

      // override ToString method
      public override string ToString()
      {
         return ("Credit Customer " + customerNumber + " " + customerName + " AmountDue is " + amountDue.ToString("C2") +
            " Interest rate is " + creditRate); // creditRate causes error
      }
   }

   // class derived from Customer
   class CreditCustomer : Customer, IComparable
   {
      public double creditRate { get; set; }

      // CreditCustomer class constructor values
      public CreditCustomer(int number, string name, double due, double rate) : base(number, name, due)
      {
         customerNumber = number;
         customerName = name;
         amountDue = due;
         creditRate = rate;
      }

      // override ToString method
      public override string ToString()
      {
         return (base.ToString() + "\nMonthly payment is " + getPaymentAmount(creditCustomer[count].amountDue));
      }

   }

   // wrapper for Main
   class Assignment06
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         // instantiate an array of 5 CreditCustomer objects
         const int NUM_OF_CUSTS = 5;
         CreditCustomer[] creditCustomer = new CreditCustomer[NUM_OF_CUSTS];

         // get user input
         for (int i = 0; i < creditCustomer.Length; i++)
         {
            Console.Write("Enter customer number: > ");
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter name: > ");
            string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter amount due: > ");
            double due = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter interest rate: > ");
            double rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            creditCustomer[i] = new CreditCustomer(number, name, due, rate);
         }

         // Print to Console Summary Section
         Console.WriteLine("\nSummary\n");
         double totalDue = 0.00;
         for (int count = 0; count < creditCustomer.Length; count++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(creditCustomer[count].ToString());
            totalDue += creditCustomer[count].amountDue;
         }
         Console.WriteLine("\nAmountDue for all Customers is {0}", totalDue.ToString("C2"));

         // Print to Console Payment Section
         Console.WriteLine("\nPayment Information\n");
         double monthlyDue = 0.00;
         for (int count = 0; count < creditCustomer.Length; count++)
         {
            double payAmt = getPaymentAmount(creditCustomer[count].amountDue);
            Console.WriteLine(creditCustomer[count].ToString());
            monthlyDue += creditCustomer[count].amountDue/24;
         }
         Console.WriteLine("\nMonthly payments for all Customers is {0}", monthlyDue.ToString("C2"));
      } // end Main

      public static double getPaymentAmount(double value)
      {
         double monthlyPayment = value / 24;
         return monthlyPayment;
      }
   } // end class wrapper for Main
```

Where I'm having trouble is in two spots:
  1) My first 'public override string ToString()' needs to pull in the creditRate from either the CreditCustomer or Main class.  I'm not sure how to pass that value from a child class to the parent class
  2) On my second 'public override string ToStrng()', I'm attempting to add an additional console output to the first override, and the value I need to pull in is the result of the very last method of the program named 'getPaymentAmount'

This is a homework assignment, so just trying to fill the requirements.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

These are the full homework requirements:

1. Create a class named Customer that implements IComparable interface.

   - Create 3 Customer class fields: Customer number, customer name, and amount due. Create automatic accessors for each field.
   - Create a Customer class constructor that takes parameters for all of the class fields and assigns the passed values through the accessors.
   - Create a default, no-argument Customer class constructor that will take no parameters and will cause default values of (9, "ZZZ", 0) to be sent to the 3-argument constructor.
   - Create an (override) Equals() method that determines two Customers are equal if they have the same Customer number.
   - Create an (override) GetHashCode() method that returns the Customer number.
   - Create an (override) ToString() method that returns a string containing the general Customer information (eg: CreditCustomer 1 russell AmountDue is $4,311.00 Interest rate is 0.01). Display the dollar amounts in currency format.
   - Implement CompareTo to compare object customer numbers for >, <, == to implement sorting for the array of objects.
2. Create a CreditCustomer class that derives from Customer and implements IComparable interface.

   - Create a class variable named Rate using an automatic accessor.
   - Create an CreditCustomer class constructor that takes parameters for the Customer class fields customer number, name, amount, and rate percent that sets the Rate CreditCustomer variable to the rate percentage. Pass the id number, name, and amount back to the base Customer class constructor.
   - Create a default, no-argument CreditCustomer class constructor that will take no parameters and will cause default values of (0, "", 0, 0) to be sent to the 4-argument CreditCustomer constructor.
   - Create an (override) ToString() method that returns a string containing the general Customer information (eg: CreditCustomer 1 russell AmountDue is $4,311.00 Interest rate is 0.01 Monthly payment is $179.63). Display the dollar amounts in currency format.
   - Implement CompareTo to compare CreditCustomer objects based on customer numbers for >, <, == to implement sorting for the array of objects.
3. In Main:

   - Create an array of five CreditCustomer objects.
   - Prompt the user for values for each of the five Customer object; do NOT allow duplicate Customer numbers and force the user to reenter the Customer when a duplicate Customer number is entered.
   - CreditCustomer objects should be sorted by Customer number before they are displayed.
   - When the five valid Customers have been entered, display them all, display a total amount due for all Customers, display the same information again with the monthly payment for each customer. See the input/output example shown below.
   - Create a static GetPaymentAmounts method that will have the current Credit customer object as a parameter and returns a double value type. Each CreditCustomer monthly payment will be 1/24 of the balance (amount due). The computed monthly individual customer payment will be returned for each CreditCustomer object in the object array.

Comment: So what exactly is the expectation if the `Customer` is not a `CreditCustomer`?  This kind of customer does not have a `creditRate`, and so it doesn't make much sense to have it in that level of `ToString`.

Comment: I'd agree,  but it's just what this homework assignment is asking for..

Comment: Can you clarify what should be printed in place of `creditRate` should this be a `Customer` that doesn't have one? (If you're not sure, you need to go to your instructor.)

Comment: added clarification to post

Comment: Yeah, that clarifies nothing.  You need to go back to your instructor to clarify here.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

You can use the cast for the parent class, but be careful when you are doing things like this because you can get StackOverflow exception :) (or just null exception)

For question 2:
You can create a common class and make your calls through this class.

I've altered the code for both options: (I removed the IComparable)

```
public static class Common
    {
        public static double getPaymentAmount(double value)
        {
            double monthlyPayment = value / 24;
            return monthlyPayment;
        }
    }

    class Customer  // class declaration
    {
        public int customerNumber { get; set; }
        public string customerName { get; set; }
        public double amountDue { get; set; }

        // Cust class constructor values assigned through accessors
        public Customer(int number, string name, double due)
        {
            customerNumber = number;
            customerName = name;
            amountDue = due;
        }

        // override ToString method
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("Credit Customer " + customerNumber + " " + customerName + " AmountDue is " + amountDue.ToString("C2") +
                " Interest rate is " + ((this as CreditCustomer!=null) ? ((CreditCustomer)this).creditRate.ToString() : "N/A")); // creditRate causes error
        }
    }

    // class derived from Customer
    class CreditCustomer : Customer
    {
        public double creditRate { get; set; }

        // CreditCustomer class constructor values
        public CreditCustomer(int number, string name, double due, double rate)
            : base(number, name, due)
        {
            customerNumber = number;
            customerName = name;
            amountDue = due;
            creditRate = rate;
        }

        // override ToString method
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (base.ToString() + "\nMonthly payment is " + Common.getPaymentAmount(this.amountDue));
        }

    }

    // wrapper for Main
    class Assignment06
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // instantiate an array of 5 CreditCustomer objects
            const int NUM_OF_CUSTS = 1;
            CreditCustomer[] creditCustomer = new CreditCustomer[NUM_OF_CUSTS];

            // get user input
            for (int i = 0; i < creditCustomer.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter customer number: > ");
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter name: > ");
                string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter amount due: > ");
                double due = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter interest rate: > ");
                double rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                creditCustomer[i] = new CreditCustomer(number, name, due, rate);
            }

            // Print to Console Summary Section
            Console.WriteLine("\nSummary\n");
            double totalDue = 0.00;
            for (int count = 0; count < creditCustomer.Length; count++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(creditCustomer[count].ToString());
                totalDue += creditCustomer[count].amountDue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nAmountDue for all Customers is {0}", totalDue.ToString("C2"));

            // Print to Console Payment Section
            Console.WriteLine("\nPayment Information\n");
            double monthlyDue = 0.00;
            for (int count = 0; count < creditCustomer.Length; count++)
            {
                double payAmt = Common.getPaymentAmount(creditCustomer[count].amountDue);
                Console.WriteLine(creditCustomer[count].ToString());
                monthlyDue += creditCustomer[count].amountDue / 24;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nMonthly payments for all Customers is {0}", monthlyDue.ToString("C2"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        } // end Main


    } // end class wrapper for Main
```

Comment: The common class worked, thank you.  As far as the casting, that works as well, but that has not been covered in my text yet, so the solution the teacher is needing must have something to do with Inheritance or getters and setters.

Comment: @T.Hill if so, i believe they made a mistake in the assignment, they said display the information of General Client, but they wrote in the .ToString() CreditClient. You cannot access the properties of a "parent".